# Rewriting the Sum of indexes i and j across the ordered real numbers x(1), x(1) ... x(n) with a modulus consideration

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, recreational-mathematics, direct-sum

Question is in image (sorry I don't know how to do the type set)

[image: Index Rewriting for Modulus]

My attempt is halfway here and I got stuck.

Given LHS

= Sum (i=1 to i=n) for { Sum (j=1 to j=n) [x(i) - x(n)] where [u] denotes modulus of u }

= Sum (i=1 to i=n) for [x(i) - x(1)] + [x(i) - x(2)] + ... + [x(i) - x(n)]

= Sum (i=1 to i=n) for (x(i) - x(1)) + (x(i) - x(2)) + (x(i) - x(i-1)) + (x(i) - x(i))

- ... + (x(i+1) - x(i)) + (x(i+2) - x(i)) + ... + (x(n) - x(i))

= Sum (i=1 to i=n) for
(   { (2i - n - 1) } x(i)  - x(1) - x(2) - ... - x(i) + x(i+1) +x(i+2) +... + x(n)  )

I am stuck here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hint:  rewrite the left hand as $2\sum_{i>j}(x_i-x_j)$.

Comment: Thanks for your clue but I still could not do it